# JS DOM innerHTML Value not changing HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am no idea why, but the `innerHTML` of some HTML ids is not working for me. I am using Opera 74 but have tried the latest version of Chrome but still no luck.
My JS code:

```
var day1max = document.getElementById('todayMax').innerHTML
var day1min = document.getElementById('todayMin').innerHTML
var day1current = document.getElementById('todayCurrent').innerHTML
var day1img = document.getElementById('todayIcon')
var day1title = document.getElementById('todayTitle').innerHTML
var day1desc = document.getElementById('todayDesc').innerHTML
day1max = today.max;
day1min = "today.min";
day1current = today.current;
day1img.setAttribute('src', today.icon);
day1title = today.title;
day1desc = today.description;
```

The today objects are re-written with a fetch API but when I enter `today.max` into the console, it return a value, eg `24`.
HTML Code:

```
<h1 id="todayMax"></h1>
<h1 id="todayMin"></h1>
<h2 id="todayCurrent"></h2>
<img src="" id="todayIcon">
<h3 id="todayTitle"></h3>
<h3 id="todayDesc"></h3>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: The values you're getting from `innerHTML` are primitive strings, they're not linked to the elements anymore. You've to set `innerHTML` of an element to change element's content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
var day1max = document.getElementById("todayMax");
var day1min = document.getElementById("todayMin");
var day1current = document.getElementById("todayCurrent");
var day1img = document.getElementById("todayIcon");
var day1title = document.getElementById("todayTitle");
var day1desc = document.getElementById("todayDesc");

day1max.innerHTML = today.max;
day1min.innerHTML = "today.min";
day1current.innerHTML = today.current;
day1img.setAttribute("src", today.icon);
day1title.innerHTML = today.title;
day1desc.innerHTML = today.description;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are almost always bad answers. Yours is no exception.

Comment: I tried it like that but it didn't work but for some reason copying your code worked. Thanks!

Comment: @TheCoder76 You might have written `innerHTML` as `innerHtml` 